# Multiple box css animation

Tags: css

I got a page who display same size multiple box (the number of box are not fixed yet, it will depend of the number of data from db).

I want to display each box with css animation one by one and one after the other one.

Is it possible not knowing how many boxes will be displayed?

Need help, thank you.

```
#list {
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 70%;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
}
#list a{
    color: #ccc;
}
#list h5 {
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
#list li {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #012257;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    opacity: 100;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-right:30px;
    animation: fadeIn 5s 1 ease-in;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

````
<?php
if ($connexion) {
 // Effectuer la requête
 $query = "SELECT * FROM asset_Services";
 $result = mysqli_query($connexion, $query);
 echo '<ul id="list">';
 // Afficher les lignes du tableau en fonction de la réponse à la requête
 $index = 0;
  if ($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $br = (($index = ($index + 1) % 4) ? "" : "<br>");
      echo '<li id="slider-'.$row["id"].'"><a href=""><h5 style="margin-top:20px">'.$row["nom"].'</h5></a>' . $br . '</li>';
    }
  }
 echo '</ul>';
 // Fermer la connexion

}
?>```
````

Comment: Assuming you keep the pattern of `id` you have shown, you can use `document.querySelectorAll("li[id^='slider-']")` to get a list of all of them, no matter how many.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking, perhaps you can add an animation delay to each one of the `<li>` that is being rendered on screen after the result is fetched from the DB.

I believe that PHP script will run on the server but you will need to use AJAX on the client side to fetch the data from the endpoint and embed it into `<li>` tags.

When you do that, it might look something like this..

```
<body>
    
    <ul id="dataList"></ul>
    
    <script>
      // Function to fetch JSON data and update the DOM
      async function fetchData() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch('your_json_data.json'); // Replace with your JSON file or API endpoint
          const data = await response.json();
    
          const dataList = document.getElementById('dataList');
    
          // Iterate through the data and create <li> tags
          data.forEach((item, index) => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent = `Name: ${item.name}, Age: ${item.age}`; // Adjust properties based on your JSON structure
    
            // Add inline style with CSS variable --index
            li.style.setProperty('--index', index);
    
            dataList.appendChild(li);
          });
    
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
      }
    
      // Call the fetchData function when the page loads
      window.onload = fetchData;
    </script>
    
    </body>
```

Within your CSS, you will need to set an animation-delay on the `<li>` selector. It will look something like this.

```
#list li {
    /* Other style declarations.. */
    animation: fadeIn 5s 1 ease-in;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--index) * 0.5s);
}
```

The idea here is to use the `--index` variable to cause each item to animation one after another in sequential order.

let me know if it works, cheers!

Comment: I never use json and I don't know how.

Comment: @Eiffel-mtl how do you populate your page with the data? Are you using a framework or just pure HTML and CSS? Could you share more about the flow from when the user request the page, data fetched from server/db, then populates the page with the data? 

This can help me to understand the problem better and give a better answer.